# Tomcat getting hung in IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

**I configured the Tomcat localhost in IntelliJ IDE but it keeps getting hung after :**

Connected to server
[2019-06-17 11:11:46,230] Artifact de.hr.cms.hessenschau.hrcms-delivery:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

17-Jun-2019 11:11:55.829 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\IDE\tools\tomcat\tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager

17-Jun-2019 11:11:55.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\IDE\tools\tomcat\tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\manager has finished in 131 ms

17-Jun-2019 11:11:57.506 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

**It just says that artifact is being deployed. Please wait ..**

Comment: Open your "Edit Configuration...", select your Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration, click Log and select all logs.  Then restart.  Look in 'Localhost' and 'Catalina' log, when tomcat has issues starting up due to config I often see errors in there since it has not yet configured the logger and one of those is the capture of System.out.

Comment: Try with a new Tomcat installation and see if it helps. Does the deployment works for the war outside of IntelliJ IDEA, in the command line?

Comment: A simple experience guess: look if you have any method/field breakpoints and remove them if they are present. These thing can make deployment super-slow.